# Linux Mint 17.1 slow after login

Tags: linux-mint

loading before the login is fast, but it takes 30-50 seconds after logging in.

Once its fully booted, it has no other speed issues. Something is bottlenecking during the login process and I don't know what that is.

I'm using the factory ATI driver and I have dual-displays. I've tried the ATI driver with no success so I reverted to the stock driver.

I've seen other people with similar issues but no solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I see on the net, it seems to be related to cinnamon.
If you try xfce you will find that it is much faster.

Give it a try and report back please

Regards

Frank

Comment: The OP doesn't appear to mention Cinnamon anywhere; and, even if this is the issue, installing a different DE isn't really a fix—more a workaround.

Comment: I decided to go to Ubuntu instead. its still a bit slow but not as much, I'm thinking its my HDD which is getting on in years, hoping to go SSD soon.

Comment: Similar issue with KDE here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269524/mint-17-2-kde-sluggish-after-login